# I want to creat a small tool to record audio,during the recording, there was a lot of extra noise during the recording

Tags: qt, audio

Thank you to see：
Development environment： QT、windows
Problem： I want to creat a small tool to  record audio,during the recording, there was a lot of extra noise during the recording. why? can you help me?

```html
function: init()
{
    outputFile.setFileName("test.raw");
    outputFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate );
    QAudioFormat format;

    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);
    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format))
    {
       qWarning()<<"default format not supported try to use nearest";
       format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    }
    audio = new QAudioInput(info, format, this);
    QTimer::singleShot(10000, this, SLOT(stopRecording()));
    audio->start(&outputFile);

    qDebug() <<"record begin!";
}

function: stopRecording()
{
    audio->stop();
    outputFile.close();
    delete audio;
    qDebug() <<"record end!";
}
```

Comment: Maybe create a MCVE (such as, basically that code plus main, with qApp->quit() added to stopRecording), which duplicates the problem, easily done in a single .cpp file.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the reason.

Comment: Great. Then you could either delete this question, or write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

record audio,You have to make sure that QT setting is the same as your System Settings.

firstly：What you need to record?  microphone or a system sound.
secondly: Set the format of it

like:

```html
QAudioFormat format;

    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
```